# ScrollView not working after ObjectAnimator animation

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout(RelativeLayout) where I have views (imageview and edittexts) some are hidden. I put this layout in ScrollView and while I focus on edittext the soft keyboard appears and if needed(if most of view are visible) scroll is activated and works fine, but if I add an animation using ObjectAnimator and translateY imageView to some upper positions , and after that focus on any edittext soft keyboard appears but scroll behaves strange, such that it scrolls only edittexts and my animated imageView goes out of screen. When keyboard disappears imageView again back to display. Please help me how I can handle this , in my opinion problem is is related with Animation such that, even if animation changed imageview position ScrollView behaves like this view is on old position and doesnt't include it in scroll.